# Get time difference in javascript ISO format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a datetime in ISO format i.e.

```
2012-06-26T01:00:44Z
```

I want to get the time difference from current time. How can I achieve this using javascript or javascript library Date.js or jquery

Comment: Difference in seconds/minutes.. which unit?

Comment: well I want to calculate timestamp. like if current time is 2012-06-26T01:00:44Z what was the time 5 minutes ago

Comment: Is it required to work in IE8 ?

Comment: yes, it is must for IE8+

Comment: but ISO is not necessary. even if it works without ISO formatted date time. thats fine

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the difference in milliseconds, you can then format it as you want

```
var diff = new Date("2012-06-26T01:00:44Z") - new Date();
```

Comment: actually I want to give the time difference in minutes and get the timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var someDate = new Date("2012-06-26T01:00:44Z");
var now = new Date();
var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var diff = Math.ceil((someDate.getTime()-now .getTime())/(one_day))
alert(diff)
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8eAQp/)

You can obviously amend the `one_day` variable to get the difference in the unit you require.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest converting ISO format to something that works cross browser.

Try this,

```
var d = "2012-06-26T01:00:44Z"; 
var someDate = new Date(d.replace(/-/g,'/').replace('T',' ').replace('Z',''));
alert(someDate - new Date());
```

**Edit:**

I guess, you need `pretty time`

Try [this](http://webdesign.onyou.ch/2010/08/04/javascript-time-ago-pretty-date/) awesome code

**Edit 2:**

You needed reverse, so try this instead

```
var old_date = new Date();
alert('Old date: ' + old_date.toGMTString())
var new_date = new Date(old_date.setMinutes(old_date.getMinutes() - 5));
alert('Date 5 minutes before: ' + new_date.toGMTString());
```

If you need timestamp,

```
alert(new_date.getTime());
```

Comment: I can parse iso format to string but I dont know how to getthe time 5 minutes a go..

Comment: See the link, I've added in my answer

Comment: no actually I need the inverse.. I want to get the timestamp that was 5 minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

in order to format date you can use this function to get the desire format of the date and you can easily change the position of day , month and year.

```
function convertFormat(inputDate)
  var date = new Date(inputDate);     
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth()+1;
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var fullYear = year + '/' + month + '/' + day
  return fullYear;
```